# haproxy anonymous frontend, authorized backend with NTLM

Tags: apache-2.4, haproxy, mod-proxy, ntlm

Need to provide an anonymous readonly access to an svn repository

AFAIK, haproxy cannot auth on backend by itself.

There's a working configuration for haproxy with basic auth. How to migrate it to NTLM? Main problem is we cannot simply add a static header because of the challenge-response mechanism.

```
frontend svn_f
  bind *:8000
  mode http
  default_backend svn_b
  acl valid_method method GET HEAD OPTIONS PROPFIND REPORT
  acl valid_path path_beg /svn/myrepo
  http-request deny unless valid_method valid_path

backend svn_b
  reqadd      Authorization:\ Basic\ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  server svn_server 192.168.2.1:443 ssl verify none
```

Maybe Apache can do this? Tried this, but it does not work:

```
SSLProxyEngine on
<VirtualHost *:8000>
KeepAlive on
ProxyPass / https://user:pass@192.168.2.1/ connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30 keepalive=On
ProxyPassReverse / https://192.168.2.1/
</VirtualHost>
```